# Angular - ngClass is not working

Tags: angular, ng-class

I have a ngClass condition like this :

```
<div [ngClass]="{'alert alert-danger': alert.type == 0,'alert alert-success': alert.type == 1}"
```

If `alert.type == 1`, my class is `alert alert-succes`, but if `alert.type = 0` my class is `alert-danger`. Why class `alert` is not here ?

Comment: I put your code in a quick [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jskHT5QEtAkjS5BbTKb6?p=preview)

Comment: @Raven Nope, it doesnt work. Inspect the element when it's red, your will only have alert-danger....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be an issue, but It isn't, read a [comment for explanation](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13107#issuecomment-263131894). But you can easily have workaround by taking common class out in `class` attribute itself.

```
<div class="alert" 
  [ngClass]="{'alert-danger': alert.type == 0, 'alert-success': alert.type == 1}"
```

[**Demo Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tcaZwOXYElP9a0lz7qjS?p=preview)

Comment: Wow.. that might be a feature but it's not very intuitive. I was stumped and it's not mentioned in the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).

Comment: @Raven did you went to through the comment link, he explained it really well :) And this was there since Angular 1.. Technically it make sense to me how ngClass works :)

Comment: @AlexCaron Are you sure? The code and plunker in this answer works fine for me.